# Pandas sort row by values of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

My data looks something like this:
[given dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVqxa.png)
just with many more rows (and different timestamps).
I now want to transform the table, so that I have one row per timestamp and the row is sorted by the the JI value and each JI value contains X,Y,Z,RX,RY,RZ and confidence. So it should look like this

```
timestamp  | JI0 | JI1 | JI2 | ... | J21 | phase
timestamp1 | (confidence|X|Y|Z|RX|RY|RZ) of JI0 | ... | (confidence|X|Y|Z|RX|RY|RZ) of JI21 | phasevalue
timestamp2 |
```

The ID value is not needed for now. I already tried to get this result by using pivot (and pivot_table), but I was not able to get all values for one joint after another, but rather all (actually not even all for some reason) values from RX for every Joint, then all values from RY for every joint and so on.

The code:

```
df.pivot_table(index='timestamp', columns='JI', values=['confidence','X','Y','Z','RX','RY','RZ'])
```

The result using the code from above: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbrJj.png)

I hope my question is understandable, otherwise I am of course willing to answer any questions.

Comment: Create a small dataset and expected show expected results.

Comment: ![I hope this helps](https://imgur.com/IQ6Z4Ti)